# Nginx virtual host loading wrong site

Tags: wordpress, nginx, virtualhost, vhosts

I have Nginx with three domains.

The sites, alphabetically are *d.com*, *g.com*, and *m.com*.

All three sites are single site WordPress installations.

*g.com* is https with a letsencrypt certificate and loads as expected.

*m.com* is not https and loads as expected

*d.com* loads *m.com* instead of its own folder.

I've been searching and reading for two weeks now and I cannot sort out what I have done wrong.

**NEW INFORMATION**

I discovered that the DNS for this was still at my old host ( mt ), it was pointing here correctly, but I decided to move it to the new host ( linode ).

Now if I use www.d.com I get the correct site loading from the correct folder. But if I leave off the www and just use d.com, I get redirected to www.m.com as a full redirect.

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        client_max_body_size 150M;

        # server_tokens off;
        server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        #fastcgi
        fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        # /snippits/ssl-params.conf
        ##

        #ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        #ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        # Logs set in server blocks
        ##
        error_log /var/log/nginx/http_error.log error;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        # /conf.d/gzip.conf
        ##

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/d.com**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name d.com www.d.com;

        include snippets/expires-headers.conf;

        root /var/www/html/d.com/public_html;

        index index.php;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/d.com/www-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/d.com/www-error.log error;

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/d.com/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }
}
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/g.com**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name g.com www.g.com;

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    ssl_certificate /var/lib/acme/live/g.com/fullchain;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/lib/acme/live/g.com/privkey;

    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
    include snippets/expires-headers.conf;

    server_name g.com www.g.com;

        root /var/www/html/g.com/public_html;
        index index.html index.php;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/g.com/www-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/g.com/www-error.log error;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        alias /var/run/acme/acme-challenge/;
    }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/g.com/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
}
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/m.com**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name m.com www.m.com;

    include snippets/expires-headers.conf;

    root /var/www/html/m.com/public_html;

    index index.php;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/m.com/www-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/m.com/www-error.log error;

    location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/m.com/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

Comment: have You symlinked or copy-ed files in available to enabled?

Comment: Yes, all three are symlinked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After moving the DNS Zone file from Media Temple to Linode, http://www.d.com started loading the WordPress install from the correct folder, though http://d.com did not.

I tried another browser and found that in the other browser both were now working.

I don't understand why moving the DNS Zone file worked here.

Comment: Right, you probably had everything cached on your usual browser, so on a different and barely used browser you would immediately get the DNS changes.

Comment: The only problem I have with that is that it was changing the address in the address bar. I've never seen a cache do that, only a redirection.

So maybe I had a redirection cached, but I still have no idea where the redirection came from.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be nothing wrong with your config, but my suspicion is that you created the config for d.com by copy/pasting the config from m.com and saved the file before making any changes and then either NGINX restarted or reloaded its configuration before you made your modifications to d.com config, which basically means that NGINX doesn't have your current configuration loaded.

You could reload the configuration. On Ubuntu/Debian is something like this:

```
sudo service nginx reload
```

You should also recheck and be absolutely sure that `/var/www/html/d.com/public_html` and `/var/www/html/m.com/public_html` are indeed serving different content.

Comment: I did create it this way but in the opposite direction. Also, I have restarted Nginx scores of time since the start of this.

Comment: Hoping on @num8er's suggestion, I have two suggestions:
- Is `/var/www/html/d.com/public_html` a symlink to `/var/www/html/m.com/public_html` or vice-versa?

Comment: Edit: Hopping*    |||    I pressed enter before adding the second suggestion: are you absolutely sure `/var/www/html/d.com/public_html` and `/var/www/html/m.com/public_html` are serving different content?

Comment: Cristiano, Please make suggestion 2 and answer so I can accept it. I double checked and I was loading the wrong database in the wp-config.php.

Comment: Scratch that. I I just changed the database in the Wp-Config.php and it is still loading the content from m.com.

And actually... It is changing the address to m.com. I type in d.com, and m.com is actually loading with m.com in the address.

Okay. Now I'm wondering if I have a DNS thing.

Comment: Did the d.com database start as a copy of the m.com one? If so, did you at least update both `siteurl` and `home` on the options table to match d.com instead of m.com? You might also have to update any post_content, post_excerpt, post meta and any other options that might have links to m.com instead of d.com

Comment: No. The database was created blank with a create database command to the MySQL.

The file structure of the document root was the only thing copied. was copied